# Unable to link to an external url (Bolt cms)

Tags: twig, href, bolt-cms, contenttype

I'm using Bolt CMS and I'm trying to create a link to an external website.

So I'm getting a record from a contenttype (this works), but when I try to link to this record using a href, my domain is added in the url.

Whatever I do, I'm unable to link to an external website.

```
<a href="{{ record.contentlink }}">Link</a>
```

links to "mydomain.com/www.externalurl.com", while I just want to be directed to www.externalurl.com.

I'm expecting the solution to be very simple, but so far I haven't found the answer... 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<a href="http://{{ record.contentlink }}">Link</a>
```

it  should work as long  as you don't have 'http://' in record.contentlink

Comment: U'r right! Ok thx a lot, this works. However another problem occurs: when the editor writes 'http://' in the record, 'http//' is printed withour the ':'.
Do you have any idea why this might be?